# Redirect does not redirect in Django

Tags: django

I'm doing a registration for a user using jquery for the event of the register button, although my createUser method correctly registers a user does, not redirect to the indicated page, but paints it by console

views.py

@csrf_exempt

def createUser(request):

```
#if request.method == 'POST':
'''    nombres = request.POST.get('nombres')
    apellidos = request.POST.get('apellidos')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    direccion = request.POST.get('direccion')
    hour = timezone.now()
    day  = timezone.now()
    myuser=User(password,day,hour,email,nombres,apellidos,direccion)
    myuser.save()
 '''  

return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/platos/')
```

def platos(request):

```
platos=Plato.objects.all()
return render(request,"core/platos.html",{'platos':platos})
```

urls.py

```
path('register/',views.createUser,name="register"),
path('platos/',views.platos,name="platos"),
```

jquery

$('#registro').click(function(){

```
    var nombres = $("#exampleInputNombresRegistrarse").val();
    var apellidos = $("#exampleInputApellidosRegistrarse").val();
    var email = $("#exampleInputEmailRegistrarse").val();
    var password = $("#exampleInputPasswordRegistrarse").val();
    var direccion=$("#exampleInputDireccionRegistrarse").val();

    if (nombres == '' || email == '' || password == '' || apellidos == '' 
    || direccion == '') {
    alert("Por favor completa todos los campos...!!!!!!");
    }
    else if(email.indexOf('@', 0) == -1 || email.indexOf('.', 0) == -1){
        alert("Por favor ingrese un correo válido...!!!!!!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Bien hecho "+nombres);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/",
            method: 'POST', // or another (GET), whatever you need
            data: {'nombres': nombres,'apellidos':apellidos,'email':email,
                    'password':password,'direccion':direccion
                    }, 
            success: function (data) {        
                // success callback
                // you can process data returned by function from views.py
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

});

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHfuQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/platos/';`inside success function of your ajax call. It'll redirect you to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/platos/`

Comment: Welcome. As this answer solves your problem, this answer expects an upvote. It'll help others to be more confident when they see this answer facing same problem.  :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, in view.py
`return redirect('/platos/')` 
Or use reverse-resolve the name technique
`return redirect(reverse('platos'))` "platos" is just reverse relationship name in that url

[for more details about redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it shows me the page by console (html), in the image of my question I show it, I do not know why it goes like this.